# Close md-dialog inside it's component.ts

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mddialog

I have a md-dialog component - `DialogComponent` - which i open from sibling component - `SiblingComponent` - and i want to close it in  `dialog.component.ts` after some actions.

`DialogComponent` basically is a form with submit button, submitting form takes me to `dialog.component.ts` function where i'm doing some validation and sending data to service.

After validation passes and data is sent i want to make some timeout and then automatically close dial window, but i dont know how to run something like `md-dialog-close` in `dialog.component.ts`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can inject an `MdDialogRef` into the *dialog component* class, and use that to close it. Example:

```
export class DialogComponent {

    constructor(private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent >) { }

    someAction() {
        // do your thing here
        this.dialogRef.close(); // <- this closes the dialog. 
        // You can also wrap it in setTimeout() if you want
    }
}
```

Comment: he's trying to reach his dialogRef from different components

Comment: actualy no, i'm trying to reach dialogRef from DialogComponent :)

Comment: That's the answer, than you so much

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here looking for a similar situation but for MatDialog

My scenario is that I had a `MatDialog` that contains and `EditParkingDialogComponent` that contains a `ParkingFormComponent`, why so complicated ? because I am reusing the `ParkingFormComponent` to be used as a form or into a dialog.

What I needed was to close the main `MatDialog` when a Parkin was updated in the `ParkingFormComponent`, example when the data was saved.

Here is what I did:

In the `ParkingFormComponent.component.ts` I emit an event when the parking is updated

```
  @Output()
  parkingUpdated: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  updateParking() {
    .....
    this.parkingUpdated.emit();
  }
```

In the `EditParkingDialogComponent.component.ts` (intermediate component)

```
  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialog) { }

  onParkingUpdated() {
      this.dialogRef.closeAll();
  }
```

In the `EditParkingDialogComponent.component.html`

```
<app-parking-form [mode]="formMode" [parkingModel]="currentParking" (parkingUpdated)="onParkingUpdated()"></app-parking-form>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to get a reference to the component you want to access by using `@ViewChild(MyComponent) myComponent;` in the parent.

From 1 sibling you need to emit an event to the parent by using `@Output() event = new EventEmitter();` and then in the parent you can access the other sibling by using it's reference.

(you don't need an @Output(), you can also create two references in the parent @ViewChild(SiblingOneComponent) & @ViewChild(SiblingTwoComponent) and a variable in the child component: parentComponent: ParentComponent. and set it (in the parent) by using SiblingOneComponent.parentComponent = this;

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking. He simply wants to close the dialog instance from within his dialog component class.